# Chromatic Modes?

Tags: theory, modes, modal

Are there names for chromatic modes? As in where the "starting note" isn't in the "key" that you're playing. For example, D major but starting on C, as it's something between Aeolian and Locrian. Then you could either have C C# D E F# G A B C or, in a more regular scale format, B# C# D E F# G A B# (dropping the B) or C D E F# G A B C (dropping the C# makes it C Lydian??). Overall I'm pretty confused and would love to know if these variations have a name, and where I can find out more. Thanks!

Comment: One underlying confusion might be: keys, scales, and modes are just ideas, and an actual musical piece can use notes from outside these sets. (Unless it decides to impose stricter rules on itself.) So a piece in D *could* include C naturals. Or it could even use the exact pitch set you described, even if there's no good label for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They won't be called modes. Modes by definition use diatonic notes, so there will be seven of them for each key. So, there are no other modes for a specific parent key. From your edit - yes, if C♯ is out, and C ♮ there instead, it's C Lydian. But at that stage, it has nothing to do with key D.

Comment: Nit-picky detail: there will be as many modes as there are members of the scale, which could be more or fewer than seven.

Comment: @Richard I'll see your nitpick and raise you one: scales with rotational symmetry have fewer modes than there are member pitches of the scale. The whole-tone scale, for example, has only one mode: itself.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as a chromatic mode.

Modes, by definition, share the same set of pitches as their parent key, but a different starting pitch. When we say that *X* is a mode of *Y*, we mean that they use the same set of notes, but they differ in starting pitch and, therefore, and more importantly, interval sequence, which is what gives them their distinct sounds.

But when learning about modes, there are two ways to think about them. One is to keep the set of pitches the same and change starting notes; the other is to keep the starting note the same and change the pitches. The former is how modes are actually derived; the latter is just a different way to conceptualize them.

- C# locrian is the seventh mode of D major. That means that if we use the same pitches as are in D major, but use C# as the starting point, we play a locrian scale.
- An alternative formulation is by comparison to C# major. Then C# locrian is understood as having lowered scale degrees 2, 3, 5, 6, and 7.

No scale containing C natural can be a mode of D major.

- If we play a scale starting on D and include F# and C natural, then we have a D mixolydian scale — a scale that uses the same pitches as G major.
- If we play a scale starting on C natural and include F#, then we have a C lydian scale — a scale that also uses the same pitches as G major.

Modes — diatonic modes — can be thought of as a sets of scales sharing the same key signature.

Answer (score 2):

I think the root of the question is whether one can use a scale that doesn't include the root of the underlying chord. One can, but it's uncommon.

For example, B minor pentatonic (B, D, E, F#, A) can sound good with C major chord, because that pentatonic is a subset of C-lydian scale. Omission of the C note adds space, so characteristic to the pentatonic scales.

I'm not aware of any special name for that.

You produced your examples a bit differently though, by adding the b2 note to a scale that doesn't contain it. The trouble with that is that in western music we normally don't distinguish more than 7 different notes in a scale. An 8 note scale sounds as if one of the notes was repeated with two different flavours. It's not wrong, it works, but categorizing it with traditional ways may not be so helpful.

- C C# D E F# G A B – this sounds like C lydian with added b2 (Db). Or, if we take D as a root, this would be D mixolydian with added natural 7, also called D [bebop scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bebop_scale).
- B# C# D E F# G A – This makes an interesting combination of small intervals in the lower half of the scale, and large ones in the upper half. You could treat it as C lydian with added b2 and omitted 7, but it could actually work very well over dominant chords. b2 and #4 (or b5) are common dominant alterations, and there is no natural 7 that would clash with b7.
- C D E F# G A B - this is just C lydian

Comment: This is a great answer, thank you!